# A proper way to init libqgit2 for QtCreator on macOS

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, qt5, qt-creator

I am a newbie to Qt development and trying to set up a dev environment on macOS with libqgit2.

I installed Qt Creator, created a blank project (CMake build system), downloaded libqgit from github and built it (after including Qt dir to CMakeLists). After that I added those lines to my project CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(LIBQGIT_DIR /Users/ash/Desktop/libqgit2/)
include_directories(${LIBQGIT_DIR})

...

target_link_libraries(untitled1 PRIVATE ${LIBQGIT_DIR})
```

After including <qgit2.h> in main.cpp I received an error:

> In included file: 'qgit2/qgitblob.h' file not found

I created a copy of libqgit2/src folder as libqgit2/qgit2, which did the trick and error changed to:

> In included file: 'libqgit2_export.h' file not found

I found that file inside libqgit2/build and copied it to libqgit2/qgit2

The error changed to:

> In included file: 'git2.h' file not found

I solwed that error by installing libgit2 with `brew install libgit2` and adding following lines to my CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(GIT_DIR /usr/local/Cellar/libgit2/1.7.1/include)
include_directories(${GIT_DIR})
```

That made my IDE build sucessfully and recognise library functions but after trying to simply init library like that:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <qgit2.h>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    LibQGit2::initLibQGit2(); // Init
    
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

I received yet another error:

> :-1: error: Undefined symbols:
> :-1: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have no idea how to proceed further and all that copying from here to there feels a bit unnatural like I am doing something wrong, is there a more correct way to set up libqgit2 with QtCreator on macOS?

Comment: The proper way is to **install** `libqgit2` project. That way, all header files will be in a single directory, which you could specify in `include_directories` command. Note also, that in `target_link_libraries` call you need to specify **files** (`.a` or `.so`), not *directories*.